# Why my django project is not visible from domain but working fine when accessed from server ip address?

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm deploying a django project with nginx on digitalocean. When i accessed my project from server ip address, it is working fine but when i visited through domain connected with it, default welcome page of nginx is shown.
After reading previous questions on stackoverflow, i figured it out that it usually happense when your domain is not in allowed host setting of django.But this is not the case this time. Here is my sllowed hosts in django settings:-

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['server-ip-address','www.saporasocial.me','.saporasocial.me','saporasocial.me']
```

You can visit [SaporaSocial](http://saporasocial.me)

How can i solve this behaviour?

**Edit**
Here is the nginx config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name saporasocial.me www.saporasocial.me server-ip-address;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {
        root /home/user/project;
}


location /media/ {
        root /home/user/project/project;
}


location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock;
}

}
```

Since i can see default nginx page, i do not think that nginx has any problem.

Comment: please add your nginx configs

Comment: @mahyar you can now see the nginx config

Comment: Have you checked the output of `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Answer (score -1):

First add your domain

```
saporasocial.me
```

in the

```
Networking > Domains > Settings
```

of DigitalOceans.com cloud. Make sure it is pointing to your droplet IP address.
Next, you will need to change the Nameserver settings for your domain in the Domain name provider's control panel.

Comment: I already did it. That is why i can access default nginx page on visiting domain